# in git bash in windows ln -s /destinations/path/ link_name just copies the destination rather than creates a link

Tags: linux, windows, symlink, git-bash, symlink-traversal

In Git bash i have run the following:

```
ln -s "//server/path/Resource/" test
```

When I check if it's worked:

```
ls -l
```

It appears as a folder rather than a symlink.
I am using windows and trying to create a symbolic link to a network location.
This is probably an easy fix but i just want a shortcut rather than copying a massive folder.

Comment: There's some explanation & workarounds here: https://superuser.com/questions/550732/use-mklink-in-msys

Answer (score 1):

make sure your git config points symbolic links as true.

core.symlinks=false

make this as true as by default it is

Comment: That's not sufficient. I have symlinks=true in the [core] section of C:\ProgramData\Git\config, and ln still copies instead of creating a symlink.